# Java BigInteger much slower than JavaScript on Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, biginteger

I had written a program for Node.js, which uses a lot of big-integer arithmetic, that I now want to run on an Android phone. I was able to happily test it on a phone using [Dory - node.js](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.tempage.dorynode&hl=en), but would like to run it in my own app. I ported it to Java and compiled it in Android Studio 3.2.1. I was also thinking Java would be faster than JavaScript. However, when I ran it, what took minutes on the phone in JavaScript, took hours in Java.

To test this, I wrote the following simple program in Java and JavaScript that just does big-integer additions:

**Java**

```
package com.example.bigintsprint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      BigInteger[] inputs = new BigInteger[1000];

      Random random = new Random();
      byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
      for(int index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++)
      {  random.nextBytes(bytes);
         inputs[index] = new BigInteger(bytes);
      }

      long startTime = System.nanoTime();

      BigInteger output = BigInteger.ZERO;
      for(int lIndex = 0; lIndex < inputs.length; lIndex++)
      for(int rIndex = 0; rIndex < inputs.length; rIndex++)
      {    output = output.add(inputs[lIndex].add(inputs[rIndex]));
      }

      System.out.println(output);
      System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0);

   }

}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const BigInt = require('big-integer');
const performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;

const SIZE = 1000;
const inputs = [];

for(let index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
   let bigInt = BigInt(0);
   for(let length = 0; length < 64; length++) {
      bigInt = bigInt.shiftLeft(8).add(BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)));
   }
   inputs.push(bigInt);
}

const startTime = performance.now();
let output = BigInt.zero;
for(let lIndex = 0; lIndex < SIZE; lIndex++) {
   for(let rIndex = 0; rIndex < SIZE; rIndex++) {
      output = output.add(inputs[lIndex].add(inputs[rIndex]));
   }
}
console.log(output);
console.log((performance.now() - startTime) / 1000);
```

Running both on the phone--the Java (running with optimisations turned on) in an Android app, the JavaScript in Dory--the Java program took 20 seconds, the JavaScript took 0.6 seconds! Why is Java so significantly slower than JavaScript at big-integer arithmetic? And is it possible to improve the Java time?

Comment: The JavaScript optimizer is likely realizing that your nested `for` loops **aren't doing anything**, and eliminates them. Java is likely not realizing that (yet, depending on when JIT is invoked). Try actually doing something in the loops, e.g. summing up a grand total.

Comment: @Andreas I sometimes use `bitCount` and then XOR the `int` results together, then print that out. Summing up will create a rather large amount of BigIntegers in addition to the ones you already have. It will be a very smart compiler to guess the number of bits in the result :)

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the question to output the result of adding all values together, updating the run-time for Java to 20 seconds, and 0.6 seconds for JavaScript

Comment: have you tried using a profiler to determinate where the time is consumed?

Comment: @MartinFrank I have tried profiling it in Java. I can't say it told me much more than that it spends its time in BigInteger's add and subtract methods (it uses subtract if it adds a negative number). It did appear to spend a lot of time in allocating int arrays and such, so I took a copy of the decompiled BigInteger and modified it to be mutable (removing all allocations, GCs, and finalizations) but that only increased the overall speed, in the test I'd done for it, from about 10 minutes down to 7.6 minutes (nowhere near as good as JavaScript, not worth rewriting the whole library for).